# Let $a, b, c$ be positive real numbers. Prove the inequality.

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a, b, c$ be positive real numbers. Prove that $$\dfrac{2a^2b^2c^2}{a^3b^3+b^3c^3+c^3a^3}+\dfrac{1}{3} \geq \dfrac{3abc}{a^3+b^3+c^3}.$$
My solutions is:
$$\dfrac{3abc}{a^3+b^3+c^3}-\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{2a^2b^2c^2}{a^3b^3+b^3c^3+c^3a^3} \leq 0.$$
As $$a^3+b^3+c^3 \geq 3abc,$$ then $$\dfrac{1}{a^3+b^3+c^3} \leq \dfrac{1}{3abc}.$$
So we have $$\dfrac{3abc}{a^3+b^3+c^3}-\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{2a^2b^2c^2}{a^3b^3+b^3c^3+c^3a^3} \leq \dfrac{3abc}{3abc}-\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{2a^2b^2c^2}{3a^2b^2c^2}=1-\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{2}{3} \leq 0.$$
I still doubt the correctness of my solution, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you have to use either $x,y,z $ or $ a,b,c$ not both .

Comment: @JanakaRodrigo thanks for noticing, edited;)

Comment: The first inequality concerning this one
$$-\dfrac{2a^2b^2c^2}{a^3b^3+b^3c^3+c^3a^3}$$
at the last step is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Let $x^3+y^3+z^3=3u$, $x^3y^3+x^3z^3+y^3z^3=3v^2$,$x^3y^3z^3=w^3$ and $u^2=tv^2$.

Thus, $t\geq1$ and we need to prove that
$$\frac{2w^2}{v^2}+1\geq\frac{3w}{u}$$ or $$2uw^2-3v^2w+uv^2\geq0.$$
Now, if $$9v^4-8u^2v^2\leq0,$$ so the inequality is obviously true.

Let $9v^4-8u^2v^2\geq0$ or $t\leq\frac{9}{8}.$

Thus, it's enough to prove that: $$w\geq\frac{3v^2+\sqrt{9v^4-8u^2v^2}}{4u}$$ or
$$w^3\geq\left(\frac{3v^2+\sqrt{9v^4-8u^2v^2}}{4u}\right)^3.$$
But by Schur $$\sum_{cyc}(a^9-a^6b^3-a^6c^3+a^3b^3c^3)\geq0$$ or
$$27u^3-27uv^2+3w^3-9uv^2+3w^3+3w^3\geq0,$$ which gives $$w^3\geq4uv^2-3u^3$$ and it's enough to prove that
$$64u^3(4uv^2-3u^3)\geq\left(3v^2+\sqrt{9v^4-8u^2v^2}\right)^3$$ or
$$64t^2(4-3t)\geq(3+\sqrt{9-8t})^3,$$ where $1\leq t\leq\frac{9}{8}.$

Now, let $\sqrt{9-8t}=p$.

Thus, $0\leq p\leq 1$, $t=\frac{9-p^2}{8}$ and we need to prove that:
$$(9-p^2)^2\left(4-\frac{3(9-p^2}{8}\right)\geq(3+p)^3$$ or $$(3-p)^2(5+3p^2)\geq8(3+p)$$ or
$$(1-p)(21-17p+15p^2-3p^3)\geq0$$ and since $$21-17p+15p^2-3p^3\geq12-24p+12p^2=12(1-p)^2\geq0,$$ we are done.

Comment: why exactly is $9^4−8^v^2 \leq 0$?

Comment: @Alice Malinova Because If $9v^4-8u^2v^2\leq0$, so the inequality is obviously true. It's enough to prove your inequality for $9v^4-8u^2v^2\geq0$.

Comment: I understand this, I do not understand where this inequality comes from;) can you explain please?

Comment: @Alice Malinova $2uw^2-3v^2w+uv^2\geq0$ is a quadratic inequality of $w$. Also, If $a>0$ so $ax^2+bx+c\geq0$ for any real $x$, when $b^2-4ac\leq0.$ In our case $b^2-4ac=9v^4-8u^2v^2.$

Comment: @Alice Malinova I solved for you at least five problems, but you did not accept even one of them. Why?

Comment: didn't I? what do you mean?

Comment: I can say with confidence that this is not about acceptance, but just my misunderstanding of some things. you really helped me a lot with examples!

Comment: @Alice Malinova There is a sigh V under up-voting and down-voting. Put this, if you want to accept.

Comment: sorry, didn't know about that;) done! can you see it now?

Comment: @Alice Malinova Thank you!

Comment: is it possible to explain this step in more details 27^3−27^2+3^3−9^2+3^3+3^3≥0 without using Schur?

Comment: @Alice Malinova I did not understand your question. The inequality, which you wrote it's Schur exactly.

Comment: sorry, I tried to ask if is it possible to explain this step in more details? How can we get 27^3−27^2+3^3−9^2+3^3+3^3≥0 from the cyclic sum? I can't see it in my head;)

Comment: Because $a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)^3-3(ab+ac+bc)(a+b+c)+3abc$. The second expression you can get by the similar way